# Converting Shape (SDE.ST_GEOMETRY) to Latitude and Longitude

Tags: convert, latitude-longitude, st-geometry

A table Oracle have a Shape field of type SDE.ST_GEOMETRY, I want to convert it to latitude and longitude.

I need the Latitude and Longitude to build dynamic maps on Google Maps.

I saw on the Internet this tip, I tried this:

```
SELECT sde.ST_X(shape) x, sde.ST_Y(shape) y FROM pontes;
```

But returned this:

> ```
>               X | Y
> ```
>
> 692789,990308064 |    7020476,32990657

I think these are coordinates (XY) ArcGIS, but I need the latitude and longitude.

**How do I convert a Shape (SDE.ST_GEOMETRY) to Latitude and Longitude?**

Answer (score 2):

This is giving you the lat/long for your geometry, but it looks like your data is in some sort of feet-based projection like state plane. If you're wanting to display the coordinates in a system that's readable by Google Maps, you'll need to transform the point. Not sure about the syntax for SDE in Oracle, but in PostGIS it's something similar to:

```
    select st_astext(st_transform(shape, 4326))
```

For additional information see the [help page](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-transform.htm).

Comment: This is close, but your parens are out of alignment, and it doesn't address geodetic transformation (geogtrans use) if the projected data is not based on GCS_WGS_1984.